# How can import CSV file data into a Postgres table

Tags: postgresql, csv

How can import CSV file data into a Postgres table? And I have a multiple delimiter like `,` and `"`.

Kindly suggeste me, hope for reply.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the `copy` and `\copy` commands?

Comment: no: I am new for using postgresql kindly suggest me in detail

Comment: Please read this page of the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY